# Почему в Firefox не работает наведение на дочерние элементы кнопки?

Tags: html, css, firefox

*(первоначальное название темы «Как сделать всплывающую подсказку при наведении на изображение, содержащееся внутри кнопки?»)*

Нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора мыши на вопросительный знак отображалась всплывающая подсказка. Спасибо.

Вот мой код:

```css
button {
  font-size: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -o-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
.StOver {
  background: AntiqueWhite;
}
.SashaOrchidea {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.SashaOrchidea:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
  <button class="StOver">Stack Overflow
    <div class="SashaOrchidea" data-title="Текст всплывающей подсказки">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/HILLGIALLO_puntointerrogativo.png" width="21" height="21" border="0" alt="">
    </div>
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: так у вас же реализовано это уже в примере

Comment: не, игеещт не дает подсказке показываться чет.

Comment: Работает в Chrome и IE11. Не работает в Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или пробуем избавиться от button средствами input[type='submit'/'button']. И через label делаем вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
  background: #39A2AE;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
label, .tooltip {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
label {
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 145px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label .tooltip {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.3)
}
.tooltip-text {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-100% - 10px);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<label for="button"><span>Кнопка</span><div class="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-question"></i><span class="tooltip-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></div></label>
<input id='button' type="submit" />
```

Comment: Ув-мый @NeedHate ,//
1) как убрать дополнительную кнопку рядом с основной? Если даже присвоить атрибуту value пустое значение, она всё равно остаётся.//

Оборачиваем кнопку в тег <a>, поскольку она должна куда-то ссылаться.//

2) Ссылка открывается лишь нажатием средней кнопки мыши, а не левой.//
3) После клика по ссылке средней кнопкой мыши сверху кнопки появляются границы всплывающей подсказки.//

[Код](http://cssdeck.com/labs/gdfxtan1). Спасибо.

Comment: 1. input присваиваем атрибут hidden // Зачем к кнопке присваивать отсылку? кнопки нужны для передачи информации из формы. Если кнопка работает как ссылка внутри страницы или на другую страницу, тогда нам не нужна кнопка, стилизованный под кнопку тэг <a> вполне справится с этой задачей. Нажатие средней кнопки как и нажатие левой - одинаково и не имеет разграничений. 3. Не понятно.

Comment: [спасибо :)](http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/EKxZQO)

Answer (score 3):

Начнём с того, что приведённый пример работает в *Google Chrome* и *Internet Explorer 11*, но не работает в *Mozilla Firefox*. Это связано с тем, что по каким-то неведомым нам причинам *Firefox* не хочет обрабатывать событие `onhover` на тэгах, лежащих внутри кнопки, обрабатывая только `onhover` на самой кнопке. Следующий код (немного не такой, как в примере, но смысл примерно тот же) также работает во всех браузерах, кроме *Firefox*:

```css
.tooltip {
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.tooltip > span {
    display: none;
}
.tooltip:hover > span {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #DDF;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!
    <span class="tooltip">?<span>Hi! I am tooltip!</span></span>
</button>
```

Чтобы он заработал в *Firefox*, его нужно изменить. Но подсказка будет появляться при наведении мыши на ***любую*** часть кнопки, а не только на вопросительный знак:

```css
.tooltip {
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.tooltip > span {
    display: none;
}
button:hover .tooltip > span  {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #DDF;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!
    <span class="tooltip">?<span>Hi! I am tooltip!</span></span>
</button>
```

Выходом из сложившейся ситуации может быть, например, самостоятельная отрисовка кнопки при помощи `div` или `span`.

Comment: [соответствующий баг](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003)

Comment: А я дам пояснение: дело в том, что в Firefox действие `:hover` не распространяется на дочерние элементы `<button>`. Баг с 2013 года известен и в репорте есть патч

Comment: Извиняюсь, можно поподробнее про отрисовку? [Спасибо](http://cssdeck.com/labs/3u04ntmn).

Comment: @СашаЧерных Думаю, для этого следует задать отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `<button>` используй `<a role=button href="#">`.

Естественно, внешнюю ссылку придётся убрать.
Хотя это в любом случае неправильно, класть кнопку внутрь ссылки.

Comment: У меня получилось (см. последний комментарий к ответу NeedHate), но вынужден был отказаться от вслывающих подсказок на сайте по причине того, что не соображу, как сделать, чтобы они не вылазили за пределы экрана. Спасибо.